# How to serialize data in example-in-example format for tensorflow-ranking?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm building a ranking model with [tensorflow-ranking](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking). I'm trying to serialize a data set in the TFRecord format and read it back at training time.

The tutorial doesn't show how to do this. There is some documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/g3doc/api_docs/python/tfr/data/parse_from_example_in_example.md) on an example-in-example data format but it's hard for me to understand: I'm not sure what the `serialized_context` or `serialized_examples` fields are or how they fit into examples and I'm not sure what the `Serialize()` function in the code block is.

Concretely, how can I write and read data in example-in-example format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context is a map from feature name to `tf.train.Feature`. The examples list is a list of maps from feature name to `tf.train.Feature`. Once you have these, the following code will create an "example-in-example":

```
context = {...}
examples = [{...}, {...}, ...]
serialized_context = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=context)).SerializeToString()
serialized_examples = tf.train.BytesList()
for example in examples:
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=example))
    serialized_examples.value.append(tf_example.SerializeToString())
example_in_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'serialized_context': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[serialized_context])),
    'serialized_examples': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=serialized_examples)
}))
```

To read the examples back, you may call

```
tfr.data.parse_from_example_in_example(example_pb,
    context_feature_spec = context_feature_spec,
    example_feature_spec = example_feature_spec)
```

where `context_feature_spec` and `example_feature_spec` are maps from feature name to `tf.io.FixedLenFeature` or `tf.io.VarLenFeature`.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Could you maybe provide a full example with some random data? (e.g. how to produce the tf.train.Feature, how to initialize the tf.io.FixedLenFeature)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend reading this article to ensure that you know how to create a `tf.Example` as well as `tf.SequenceExample` (which by the way, is the other data format supported by TF-Ranking):

[Tensorflow Records? What they are and how to use them](https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564)

In the second part of this article, you will see that a `tf.SequenceExample` has two components: 1) Context and 2)Sequence (or examples). This is the same idea that `Example-in-Example` is trying to implement. Basically, context is the set of features that are independent of the items that you want to rank (a search query in the case of search, or user features in the case of a recommendation system) and the sequence part is a list of items (aka examples). This could be a list of documents (in search) or movies (in recommendation).

Once you are comfortable with `tf.Example`, `Example-in-Example` will be easier to understand. Take a look at this piece of code for how to create an `EIE` instance:

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/tensorflow/ranking/95/518480361

1) bundle context features together in a `tf.Example` object and serialize it

2) bundle sequence(example) features (each of which could contain a list of values) in another `tf.Example` object and serialize this one too.

3) wrap these inside a parent `tf.Example`

4) (if you're writing to tfrecords) serialize the parent `tf.Example` object and write to your tfrecord file.